# how to get the value (or index) from a picker and compare it to the value of an attribute of an entity?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I have a problem in returning the value from a picker and comparing it to the value of an attribute. Basically, i have a Floor entity which has a attribute "floorNumber". From the picker I need to get the floor number and match it to the correct entity object so I can start assigning rooms to individual floors. I have implemented the delegate and the data source for the picker and looked at other questions on this site but I'm getting a bit confused. 
Please have look at my implementation and please tell me what am I doing wrong. I have an optional "pickedFloor" which is nil even though it is being set and if I try to unwrap it it will crash it. Thank you for your help

```
class SetNumberOfRoomsPerFloor: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    //MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet private weak var floorPicker: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet private weak var numberOfRoomsPerFloor: UITextField!

    private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    internal var floorValue: Int16?

    private var convertedFloorValues = [String]()

    private var storedFloors = [Floors]()

    private var pickedFloor: Int16?

    private var roomNumberValue: Int16 {
        get {
            return Int16(numberOfRoomsPerFloor.text!)!
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        floorPicker.delegate = self
        floorPicker.dataSource = self
        loadFloorData()
        spinnerItems()
    }

    @IBAction func setTheFloors(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if storedFloors.count > 0 {
            if storedFloors.first?.floorNumber == pickedFloor {
                storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms = roomNumberValue
                print("\(storedFloors.first?.floorNumber) + \(storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms)")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextStep(_ sender: UIButton) {}

    private func loadFloorData() {
        let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
        do {
            storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
        } catch {
            print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func spinnerItems() {
        for i in 0...floorValue! - 1 {
            convertedFloorValues.append(String(i))
        }
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return convertedFloorValues.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return convertedFloorValues[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let selection = Int16(convertedFloorValues[row]) // not sure I have to do this part.
        pickedFloor = selection
    }
}
```

Comment: Is is possible that it is larger than an Int16? Can I see the actual error? The problem is likely that pickedFloor is trying to be unwrapped before you move the pickerView. PickerView doesn't call didSelectRow on the component it is initialized to, so if you want that you have to initialize pickedFloor manually to the same spot that the pickerView starts at.

Comment: the error is "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping value" of pickedFloor in the when it check for equality in setTheFloors method. If I take the ! out then the code block does not get executed. If I put ! then error. It does not get assigned the value of the selected item or the index. I have moved the picker as I tested it and the same thing happens. How would I assign the selected row value or index to the pickedFloor variable? Thank you

Comment: Inside didSelectRow, print convertedFloorValues before you do the other lines and see what it says then.

Comment: Ok. so what happens is this. If I don't move the picker at all and leave the first item then when I try to assign the room value for the floor it will crash. If I move the picker to another item and assign rooms it does it. And if i return to the first one it will also assign it. Any idea of why this is happening? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside this function, you should do this

```
private func spinnerItems() {
    for i in 0...floorValue! - 1 {
        convertedFloorValues.append(String(i))
    }
    if convertedFloorValues.count >= 1 {
        pickedFloor = Int16(convertedFloorValues[0])
    }
}
```

Like I said in the comments, didSelectRow never gets called if you don't actually move the picker view.

Comment: ok, got it. Makes sense. Thank you very much. Would you please confirm that ssuming that the user sets rooms for all floors will the function implementation cycle through all the entity objects of type Floor or just the first one? Thank you

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. I am also quite confused as to why you convert a string into an int16.

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the setTheFloors functions. Thank you

Comment: This code just initializes pickedFloor to the first object in the pickerView so that the picker view always represents the data inside of pickedFloor even before you move it.

Answer (score 1):

If the user hasn't selected anything in `pickerview` then `pickedFloor` will be nil.Try this.

```
@IBAction func setTheFloors(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if storedFloors.count > 0 {
        if storedFloors.first?.floorNumber == convertedFloorValues[floorPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] {
            storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms = roomNumberValue
            print("\(storedFloors.first?.floorNumber) + \(storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have a bit of confusion here as well and maybe you could help me out. Assuming that the user sets rooms for all floors will the function implementation cycle through all the entity objects of type Floor or just the first one? Thank you

Comment: would i still need the didSelectRow function if I implement your solution?

Comment: No. You dont need the function and variable `pickedFloor`.